# SQL Server 2008 connectionString question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to connect to my SQL Server 2008 database with ASP.NET MVC 3. Here is my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AppConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=UserName;Password=PassWord;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

When I try to query something in my DbContext I get this exception:

> - $exception  {"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."} System.Exception {System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException}
> - InnerException  {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"}   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Right click on server name on object explorer, select properties-> Connections, Check if "allow remote connections to server" is checked.

Comment: Yes it is checked, thanks. :)

Comment: Can you show the code where you are trying to connect to DB?

Comment: I have same problem, I have about 20 ASP, ASP.NET and MVC2 applications working on same IIS server/dev machines, connecting same SQL 2008 R2 servers. It's sure for me that the problem is related to EF4.1, that is the only changed think. Regards

Answer (score 3):

First check if your mssqlserver services are running fine. Just run `net start mssqlserver` in your command prompt.

Then try changing the connection string `Data Source=(local)` to `Data Source=.`

All the above is assuming that you have sql server installed in your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

That error means that either the name of your Data Source in your connectionstring is wrong or that your sql server is not configured to allow remote connections : see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/7798/how-to-enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-2008/7801#7801) how to fix it.

Comment: It is configured to allow remote connections, and I tried various data source name... still not working :S thanks

Comment: In the comments of your question you say that you already checked if your sql server allows remote connections. In the link of my answer however, it says you also have to check if the TCP/IP protocol is enabled for your sql server. Did you do that ?

Comment: @Semvanmeenen : I checked my configuration and yes it is enabled :S Thanks anyways

Comment: @Tom Ok, could you check if the user you connect with has the correct rights ? In sql server management studio you can see that under <your server>\security\logins\user, find your user and double click on it. In the tab status the options 'grant' and 'enabled' must be chosen.

Comment: @Semvanmeenen Yes they are checked as well. Thanks

Comment: @Tom Could you do 'netstat -ano | findstr 1433' in a dos prompt ? This will list all connections and listening ports on your pc with the number 1433 in it. 1433 is the default port for sql server. You should see something like this  'TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5693'. If not, sql server is listening on another port or not listening at all.

Comment: @Tom In sql server management studio, could you right-click on the server, click on properties and see if in the tab security 'Sql server and windows authentication mode' is selected ?

Comment: @Tom Hm, I'm getting a bit stumped here. Could you try the instructions on [this page](http://www.lockergnome.com/tsilb/2007/12/08/create-a-sql-connectionstring-easily/) to create a connectionstring and compare it with yours ? It's also possible that the problem is your SQL server browser service not running. If that doesn't work, I'm sorry to say I'm out of ideas. You could maybe migrate the question to http://serverfault.com .

Answer (score 2):

Can you ping the server?

You can create a new empty text file, rename it to test.udl, double click on it and create your connection string that way. (A dialog will open and you can select provider, server, database etc).

also, have a look at w[ww.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for example connection strings

There is also the instance to take into account.  eg if you use sqlexpress it may be (local)\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: I got my connection string on that website :) And yes I can ping it since I can access it with SQL Server Management Studio and I'm using the same host to connect :S

Answer (score 2):

Besides (local) try (localhost) or 127.0.0.1 (loopback address - and no place like ;-)

Also a single period will "." resolve to the local machine.

Your connection string and the advice above assumes that you are trying to connect to an unnamed, default instance. If your server instance is named then you need to include that as part of your conn string, like: .\ServerName

More great info can be found at: http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: @Paul, For clients shipped with SQL Server 2005 and beyond, all of (local), ., and localhost are equivalent and are not tied to any particular protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and these are the steps that helped me:

1) Your application must have an App.config containing a connectionstring named with the same name as your class that inherited from DbContext. In my case "TestEF_CF.ProductContext".

```
<add name="TestEF_CF.ProductContext" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ef_cf_test;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

2) The database cannot be created before you start to use it. Just set the Initial Catalogue to the name you want Entity Framework to create when it autocreate the database.

See my stackowerflow question for more information if you need it:
[Entity Framework 4.1 Code First Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686693/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-freeze/6698776#6698776)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the InnerException it's possible that what you actually have is a Login issue.

What I had to do to fix this was, change the account the DefaultAppPool runs as, to NetworkService (go to Advanced Settings and change Process Model, Identity) and then pick an account which has access to your database.

Assuming of course your app is running in IIS using the DefaultAppPool.

I made it NetworkService and granted the NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE user access to my existing database.

This then allowed me to connect. My case might be specific but I thought I'd share just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
        SqlConnection [object name];
        [object name] = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server_address/name;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Integrated Security=True");
        [object name].Open();
```

**Note:** The square brackets which is shown should not be putted, only object name have to be placed.
Server_address : Your Computer name.
myDatabase : your Database name.